# Django template: load numbered img to html

Tags: python, html, django-templates

I am trying to loop through the database count to insert img in a html, but cannot get the {static} command work. Specifically:

import the list from views.py:

```
queryset = db_imNewChk.objects.exclude(N_tag=u'').order_by("d_Rank")
        for p in queryset:
            if (p.gp_Email):
                if (c_email):
                    if not("<li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"{% static '/img/email_icon"+p.gp_Email+".png' %}\"  width=\"20%\" style=\"padding: 3px\"></a></li>" in c_email):
                        c_email.append("<li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"{% static '/img/email_icon"+p.gp_Email+".png' %}\"  width=\"20%\" style=\"padding: 3px\"></a></li>")
                else:
                    c_email.append("<li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"{% static '/img/email_icon"+p.gp_Email+".png' %}\"  width=\"20%\" style=\"padding: 3px\"></a></li>")
...
return render(request, 'exportnews.html', {'table': listExport, 'table2': listExport1, 'table_count': q_size, 'count_email' : sorted(c_email)})
```

Then in the django template exportnews.html:

```
{% load static %}
        <td style="width:350px;height:80px;" rowspan="3" colspan="2">
            <ul class="images">
                {% for field in count_email %}
                    {{field|safe}}

                {% endfor %}
            </ul></td>
```

What I want to achieve is the  like this:

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/email_icon1.png' %}" width="20%" style="padding: 3px"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/email_icon2.png' %}" width="20%" style="padding: 3px"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/email_icon3.png' %}" width="20%" style="padding: 3px"></a></li>
```

However, instead the html code rendered is like this:

```
<li><a href="#"><img src="{% static '/img/email_icon1.png' %}" width="20%" style="padding: 3px"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="{% static '/img/email_icon2.png' %}" width="20%" style="padding: 3px"></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="{% static '/img/email_icon3.png' %}" width="20%" style="padding: 3px"></a></li>
```

So, it seems the {%static%} did not work. Could anyone advise as to solving this problem? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the `safe` filter is for, getting stuff rendered verbatim. You should keep the html rendering in the template. Simplify your view:

```
# views.py
...
c_email = set()  # easier than list
queryset = db_imNewChk.objects.exclude(N_tag=u'').order_by("d_Rank")
for p in queryset:
    if p.gp_Email:
        c_email.add(p.gp_Email)
...
return render(request, 'exportnews.html', {..., 'count_email': sorted(c_email)})
```

Then, render stuff in the template, e.g. using the [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter. You would have to use the `with` construction because the [`static` tag only works with either a string literal or a variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#static):

```
{% for foo in count_email %}
  {% with '/img/email_icon'|add:foo|add:'.png' as static_bar %}
    <li><a href="#"><img src="{% static static_bar %}"  width="20%" style="padding: 3px"></a></li>
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! It works. Haven't learned about set in Python before, really a great lesson with these new usage!